# Concept Behind Geographical Position Retrieving

Tags: java, google-maps, geolocation, location, gis

For getting Geographical Position of a user we have so many API's can any one tell me what is the concept behind this? How these api's can detect the geographical co ordinates of a user.

Please Explain

Thanks and Regards,

Sunny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any particular API that you are talking about?

As far as I know, there are 2 ways in general

1. GPS-enabled devices: So the device itself that know its own geolocation through it's GPS system
2. Through who you are connected to: a) If you are mobile device, they can pinpoint your location through figuring out the towers you are connected to, or b) If you are on an internet / wi-fi connection, it can be figured out from there.

Comment: What a Quick Response I really love using stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely upon the API.

Some APIs are dependent on a piece of hardware (such as a smartphone) that utilizes an inbuilt GPS.

Other APIs attempt to use WiFi and/or IP data to attempt a crude calculation for your location. Google's MyLocation feature is an example of this, it uses information gathered by your browser to estimate your location. Here's a link to an article discussing Google's use of WiFi/IP to calculate users positions:

[Google MyLocation](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=153807)

Others such as Google, Bing, or ESRI map based APIs allow you to query their maps to receive coordinate information about a specific address that the user inputs. If you already know users are going to access your application from a relatively small geographic area, you can submit the query on their behalf and use it to create a map based on this area (ie: a city, college campus, etc...), or to obtain a set of geographic coordinates when all you have are the addresses  (ie: a list of restaurants, apartments, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ehow.com/how-does_4965061_gps-work-mobile-phones.html
or
[How does GPS in a mobile phone work exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637/how-does-gps-in-a-mobile-phone-work-exactly)